# Como calcular reportes de una semana postgree

Tags: javascript, postgresql, vue.js

necesito generar un reporte semanal de algunos datos que tengo en mi base de datos, pero las semanas no las ingresa el usuario, esa semana se calcula dinamicamente. Por ejemplo yo ingreso a mi sistema ahora y me debe de dar un reporte de mis datos desde el lunes (Que comenzo la semana) hasta el dia de ahora.

**Mi posible solucion**

Tenia pensado restarle 7 dias a la fecha de la que ingreso para contar una semana, pero seria ilogico que entrara el primer dia del mes a mi sistema, porque la resta me quedaria con numeros negativos.

¿Puedo hacer esa validacion con JavaScript?

Comment: ¿Por qué no haces la validación directamente en tu BDD (los calculos en BDD pueden ser hasta 10 veces más rápidos)? PD: deberías de comartir la estructura o datos de ejemplo de tu BDD para darnos mejor idea.

Answer (score 0):

En tu api, donde generas el query para consultarlo, puedes obtener el día de la semana en el cual estas haciendo la consulta `moment().day()` y restarlo a la fecha del día de hoy para saber que día era el lunes.

Ejemplo: hoy es 18 de abril, si usamos `moment().day()`, nos dará que es el día `6`
entonces, con `moment` restamos los 6 - 1 días a la fecha y sabremos que día era el lunes.

Ahora ya solo has tu query consultando los registros entre esas dos fechas.